# Try to reduce execution time but fail

Tags: c++, function, time

Assume there is a set of points and almost every points are inside a quadrilateral. But a few are not. I want to know which points are not inside the quadrilateral. 
So the function looks like this.

```
bool isInside(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d, Point p) // a,b,c,d are the points consist of the quadrilateral.
{
    if(orientation(a, b, p) < 0)
        return false;
    else if(orientation(b, c, p) < 0)
        return false;
    else if(orientation(c, d, p) < 0)
        return false;
    else if(orientation(d, a, p) < 0)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}
```

I wanted to reduce the number to call the orientation function and the orientation function looks like.

```
int orientation(const Point& p, const Point& q, const Point& r)
{
  double val = (q.x - p.x) * (r.y - p.y) - (q.y - p.y) * (r.x - p.x);

  if (val == 0)
    return 0; // colinear
  return (val < 0) ? -1 : 1; // right or left
}
```

So I modified the function isInside like this.

```
bool isInside(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d, Point p) 
{
    int result;

    if(p.x <= b.x)
    {
       result = orientation(a, b, p);
    }

    else
    {
      result = orientation(b, c, p);
    }

    if(result == -1) return false;

    if(p.x <= d.x)
    {
      result = orientation(a, d, p);
    }

    else
    {
       result = orientation(d, c, p);
    }

    return (result == -1) ? true : false;
}
```

By this, the number of calling the orientation function reduces almost half(if there are more than 100,000 points it is a huge amount of number). However, it seems it does not affect the time taken and sometimes takes more. 
I don't know how come this happens even though it reduces a lot of function calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Compiler Optimizations

It would be a good idea to check whether or not you are building with optimizations enabled. If you are building your application in debug mode, the compiler may not be optimizing your code. If you are, try running in release mode. It may build your application with optimizations enabled, or a higher level of optimization. This way, you can potentially leave your code as is, with little worrying about optimizing your code (Unless fast performance is absolutely necessary).

### Quatitative Results

You could also add test code, that will allow you to get quantitative performance results (Running function x() n times takes m seconds, so each x() call takes m divided by n seconds). Then, you should be able to figure out which block of code is taking the most time.

An example of how you can go about doing the above (Without writing it for you) would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

//Doesn't matter where it is called, just using main as an example
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int numRuns = 1000000; //Or passed in to allow changing # of runs
                         //without rebuilding: int numRuns = atoi(argv[1]);

  //Code to initialize Point a, b, c, d, and p.

  high_resolution_clock::time_point orien_start_time = high_resolution_clock::now();
  for(int i = 0; i < numRuns; ++i)
  {
    orientation(a, b, p); //Ignore the return value
  }
  high_resolution_clock::time_point orien_end_time = high_resolution_clock::now();

  high_resolution_clock::time_point orien_start_time = high_resolution_clock::now();
  for(int i = 0; i < numRuns; ++i)
  {
    isInside(a, b, c, d, p); //Ignore the return value
  }
  high_resolution_clock::time_point orien_end_time = high_resolution_clock::now();

  //Format and print/log the results
}
```

Then, with those time points, you can calculate how long each function takes to run. You can then use these numbers to pinpoint where exactly your application is slowing down. Going this route, you can test your old implementation vs. your new implementation, and see if the new way is infact faster. You could even try different sets of Points, to see if that changes application performance (For example, try both functions with points p1 through p5, then try both again with p6 through p10).

**Note:** There are a lot of things that can effect application performance outside of the code you write, which is why I used one million for the hard coded `numRuns`. If you go with a small number of iterations, your execution time per function call can swing pretty drastically depending on what else is running on your system. My recommendation for gathering quantitative results would be to run the test(s) on a freshly rebooted system where your application is the only user process running, that way it doesn't have to share as many resources with other applications.